# Removing column from dataframe while writing into csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert txt into csv and reading that csv into dataframe. But while writing into csv and deleting all the empty columns there is an extra empty column that still remains. I don't know how to remove it while writing it into the csv file.

"Face.txt" contains values separated by ','.I have removed empty values using dropna as shown in the code below

```
import csv

with open('Face.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('Face.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('ImageName', 'Valence','property1','property2','property3','property4','property5','property6','property7','property8','property9','property10','property11','property12','property13','property14','property15','property16','property17','property18','property19','property20','property21','property22'))
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

This causes alternative empty columns in Face.csv. Hence:-

```
from pandas.io.parsers import read_csv
data = read_csv('Face.csv')
filtered_data = data.dropna(axis='columns', how='all')
filtered_data.to_csv('Face2.csv')
```

There is still 1 column empty even after trying the above code.

What I expect :-

---

ImageName | Valence | property1 ......

---

Name1.mat | Negative| 0.02212 ......

---

What I see :-

---

...................| ImageName| Valence | property1 ......

---

Name1.mat |...................|Negative| 0.02212 ......

Face.csv

---

ImageName | Valence | property1| property2|property3|property4......

---

Name1.mat | ........|  Negative| .........|0.02212  |..........

---

Comment: Are the empty values `NaN` or empty strings?

Comment: @HS-nebula : The empty values are empty strings. They don't show up in Python output. But are present when you open the csv files.

Comment: Then using `dropna` won't drop those columns. You could handle this two ways: 1) as you read the csv, add `na_values=''` to `pd.read_csv`, telling pandas to interpret empty strings as `NaN` values, or 2) after reading in the CSV, use `df = df.replace('', np.nan)` (import numpy as np) to replace the emptry strings with `NaN` before using `dropna`

Comment: @HS-nebula : I tried doing that. It's still not working I'm afraid! The dropna in general is helpful in removing all the blank columns except just the first column as shown above in my question (and poor representation! ).

Comment: Can you add some sample data from `Face.csv'?